# Adding a .jar License file to a Docker image's classpath?

Tags: java, docker, db2, microservices

I have a springboot application that connects to a DB2 database and then retrieves some data and provides it with a REST endpoint. To facilitate this a license is added to the classpath of the application that allows it to communicate with the DB2 database. This works. But when i build and image and run that image locally i get an error that states that the license is not there.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1569854043909,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException",
    "message": "Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][t4][10509][13454][4.26.14] Connection to the data server failed. The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid \nor was not activated for the DB2 for z/OS subsystem. If you are connecting directly to \nthe data server and using DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z, perform the \nactivation step by running the activation program in the license activation kit.  \nIf you are using any other edition of DB2 Connect, obtain the license file, \ndb2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, from the license activation kit, and follow the installation \ndirections to include the license file in the class path. ERRORCODE=-4230, SQLSTATE=42968",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

I am assuming that is because the license is now not included in the Docker containers Classpath. I have researched this a fair bit and can't see any pointers on how i would do this. So any help would be appreciated.

My License is held within a lib folder in the projects root and is a jar file.

My docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/mydb2jdbcproject-1.jar mydb2jdbcproject-1.jar
COPY lib/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
#CLASSPATH: lib/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","mydb2jdbcproject-1.jar"]
```

Comment: I would put the Db2 license file into the license subdirectory of your Db2-client (which should also be in your image), and set CLASSPATH to include that full path and filename. Your question shows the license file going into the root (not into the lib directory), and your Dockerfile has the CLASSPATH commented-out. I would use ENV to set CLASSPATH , or a RUN statement to SET CLASSPATH etc.

Comment: @mao I have added it to the java lib library and ran it, no luck. I then set the classpath to its position with `ENV CLASSPATH:----` and no luck as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change the CMD used to manually set multiple classpaths before running and for some reason it wouldn't work with -jar so i had to run via the launcher class.

The resulting dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /opt/mvp2/db2jdbc /opt/mvp2/app

COPY target/db2new-0.1.jar /opt/mvp2/app/
COPY jdbc/db2jcc4.jar  /opt/mvp2/db2jdbc/
COPY jdbc/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar  /opt/mvp2/db2jdbc/

CMD ["java","-classpath","/opt/mvp2/db2jdbc/db2jcc4.jar:/opt/mvp2/db2jdbc/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar:/opt/mvp2/app/db2new-0.1.jar:.","org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```